# Create a map value that modifies a previous value

Tags: css, sass, mapping

In SCSS, I have this map of colors:

```
$color-map: (
  'b': #000,
  'f': orange,
  's': darken(#{f}, 50%), //not working, any ideas?
);
```

This is a small part of my SCSS code. I want to be able to darken the value of 'f' programmatically. Any ideas how I can tweak the code to work? (it currently throws an error).

Comment: Isn't the syntax `#{$f}`?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan usually it is, I think. Not in this case though. Think it's because I am using strings rather than variables

Comment: Ah, ok. Not really an expert on Scss

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the map before you can access any of its values. In other words, you will need an extra step (using `map-merge`) to make this work:

```scss
// Initialize the map
$color-map: (
  'b': #000,
  'f': orange
);

// Add new color based on existing color
$color-map: map-merge($color-map, (
  's': darken(map-get($color-map, 'f'), 25%)
));
```